# FFMPEG: sws_scale does not produce any data in target frame

Tags: image, ffmpeg

I use FFMPEG to decode H264 stream. After I get decoded YUV420 frames I want to convert them into RGB24.

```
struct SwsContext * ctx = NULL;

// frame is AVFrame in YUV420 obtained from decoder. It has all three strides and seem to be valid.

if (ctx == NULL)
                {
                    ctx = sws_getContext(frame->width, frame->height, frame->format, frame->width, frame->height,
                        AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_BICUBIC, 0, 0, 0);
                }

            AVFrame* frame2 = av_frame_alloc();

            int num_bytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, frame->width, frame->height, 32);

            uint8_t* frame2_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(num_bytes * sizeof(uint8_t));

            int size = av_image_fill_arrays(frame2->data, frame2->linesize, frame2_buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, frame->width, frame->height, 32);

            int height_of_output = sws_scale(ctx, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, frame->height, frame2->data, frame2->linesize);

            callbackFullRGB(state, frameIndex, 0, frame2->data[0], num_bytes, (__int32)frame2->format, (__int32)frame2->width, (__int32)frame2->height);

            av_frame_free(&frame2);
```

However frame2 has no resolution set, pixel format is -1 and data buffer is empty. I have 1280x720 input, stride length is set to 3840 for output frame which is correct. sws_scale also returns 720 as a result - no errors, no exceptions.

What might be wrong?

Comment: Try to not allocate the frame buffer yourself. Instead allocate the frame first, then set it's width, height and format. And then call `av_frame_get_buffer` on it: 
 `AvFrame* frame2 = av_frame_alloc(); frame2->format = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24; frame2->width = frame->width; frame2->height = frame->height; av_frame_get_buffer(frame2, 0);`

Comment: @Crigges, thanks for the reply. Tried that, but result is the same. To me it looks like sws_scale just fails to decode internally, but somehow does not produce exceptions. I've also updated my libs to latest stable version - 4.1.3 x64, no changes.

Comment: If you have OpenCV available run this snippet pls: https://pastebin.com/DVDTJrDX It will create a Mat directly from the AvFrame data member and writes it as .png to the disk. If this doesn't fail and the .png is valid you can be sure the AvFrame is valid. Also link your updated code pls.

Comment: The code looks correct.  Try to go trough with a debugger and confirm the input values make sense.  Does the code run on the command line?  Normally, ffmepg outputs useful debug messages.

Comment: @Crigges ah.. this fixed my memory leak. God bless you :)